# Parsing Double/Int from Jtextfield Input

Tags: java, parsing, try-catch, jtextfield, numberformatexception

I'm new in Java and I'm now trying to create a program that receive value from user using `JTextfield` and use the value to perform some calculation. I've encountered a problem that the `JTextfield` will have `NumberFormatException` Error 
when I trying to compile it. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class VehicleParking {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      JTextField inh = new JTextField(2);
      JTextField inm = new JTextField(2);
      JTextField outh = new JTextField(2);
      JTextField outm = new JTextField(2);

      JPanel InPanel = new JPanel();
      InPanel.add(new JLabel("In Hours: "));
      InPanel.add(inh);
      String inhour = inh.getText();
      double inhourInput = Double.valueOf(inhour);
      InPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
      InPanel.add(new JLabel("Minutes :"));
      InPanel.add(inm);
      String inminute = inm.getText();
      double inminuteInput = Double.valueOf(inminute);

      JPanel OutPanel = new JPanel();


      OutPanel.add(new JLabel("Out Hours: "));
      OutPanel.add(outh);
      String outhour = outh.getText();
      double outhourInput = Double.valueOf(outhour);
      OutPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
      OutPanel.add(new JLabel("Minutes :"));
      OutPanel.add(outm);
      String outminute = outm.getText();
      double outminuteInput = Double.valueOf(outminute);
```

And here is what i get when i try to compile it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)
    at VehicleParking.main(VehicleParking.java:23)
```

There're more at the bottom for display and arithmetic purpose.
Also, I've tried to use the try and catch, but it doesn't solve my problem at all.(Even more error were shown up.) Here are my full program after using the try and catch to try to solve the Number Format Exception problem.(I know it's somehow too long for such simple arithmetic program. Sorry.)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class VehicleParking {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      JTextField inh = new JTextField(2);
      JTextField inm = new JTextField(2);
      JTextField outh = new JTextField(2);
      JTextField outm = new JTextField(2);

      JPanel InPanel = new JPanel();
      InPanel.add(new JLabel("In Hours: "));
      InPanel.add(inh);
      InPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
      InPanel.add(new JLabel("Minutes :"));
      InPanel.add(inm);

      JPanel OutPanel = new JPanel();


      OutPanel.add(new JLabel("Out Hours: "));
      OutPanel.add(outh);
      OutPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
      OutPanel.add(new JLabel("Minutes :"));
      OutPanel.add(outm);




      int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, InPanel, "Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (choice == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                {
                    try
                        {String inhour = inh.getText();
                        double inhourInput = Double.valueOf(inhour);}
                    catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        if (inhour == null || inhour.equals(""))
                            {inhourInput = 0.0;}
                        else
                            {inhourInput = 0.0;}}


                    try
                        {String inminute = inm.getText();
                        double inminuteInput = Double.valueOf(inminute);}
                    catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        if (inminute == null || inminute.equals(""))
                            {inminuteInput = 0.0;}
                        else
                            {inminuteInput = 0.0;}}

                    int choice2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, OutPanel, "Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    if (choice2 == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                        {
                            try
                                {String outhour = outh.getText();
                                double outhourInput = Double.valueOf(outhour);}
                            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                                if (outhour == null || outhour.equals(""))
                                    {outhourInput = 0.0;}
                                else
                                    {outhourInput = 0.0;}}

                            try
                                {String outminute = outm.getText();
                                double outminuteInput = Double.valueOf(outminute);}
                            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                                if (outminute == null || outminute.equals(""))
                                    {outminuteInput = 0.0;}
                                else
                                    {outminuteInput = 0.0;}}
                        double hour = outhourInput - inhourInput;
                        double minute = outminuteInput - inminuteInput;
                        String[] VehicleType = {"Car","Van","Bus","Lorry"};
                        String typeVehicle =(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Choose vehicle type: ","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                                                                null,VehicleType,VehicleType[0]);
                        switch (typeVehicle)
                            {case "Car" :   if (minute <0)
                                                {minute = minute +60;
                                                hour = hour - 1;
                                                double calcalateDuration = hour + (minute/60);
                                                double fee = calcalateDuration;
                                                String show = "Parking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,show,"Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please take your receipt.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                String receipt =    "In time: "+inhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nOut time: "+outhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nDuration: "+hour+"hours and "+minute+"minutes."+
                                                                    "\nVehicle Type: "+typeVehicle+
                                                                    "\nParking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,receipt,"Vehicle Parking System - Parking Receipt",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                                            else
                                                {double calcalateDuration = hour + (minute/60);
                                                double fee = calcalateDuration;
                                                String show = "Parking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,show,"Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please take your receipt.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                String receipt =    "In time: "+inhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nOut time: "+outhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nDuration: "+hour+"hours and "+minute+"minutes."+
                                                                    "\nVehicle Type: "+typeVehicle+
                                                                    "\nParking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,receipt,"Vehicle Parking System - Parking Receipt",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                                            break;

                            case "Van"  :   if (minute <0)
                                                {minute = minute +60;
                                                hour = hour - 1;
                                                double calcalateDuration = hour + (minute/60);
                                                double fee = calcalateDuration*120/100;
                                                String show = "Parking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,show,"Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please take your receipt.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                String receipt =    "In time: "+inhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nOut time: "+outhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nDuration: "+hour+"hours and "+minute+"minutes."+
                                                                    "\nVehicle Type: "+typeVehicle+
                                                                    "\nParking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,receipt,"Vehicle Parking System - Parking Receipt",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                                            else
                                                {double calcalateDuration = hour + (minute/60);
                                                double fee = calcalateDuration*120/100;
                                                String show = "Parking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,show,"Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please take your receipt.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                String receipt =    "In time: "+inhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nOut time: "+outhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nDuration: "+hour+"hours and "+minute+"minutes."+
                                                                    "\nVehicle Type: "+typeVehicle+
                                                                    "\nParking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,receipt,"Vehicle Parking System - Parking Receipt",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                                            break;
                            case "Bus"  :   if (minute <0)
                                                {minute = minute +60;
                                                hour = hour - 1;
                                                double calcalateDuration = hour + (minute/60);
                                                double fee = calcalateDuration*140/100;
                                                String show = "Parking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,show,"Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please take your receipt.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                String receipt =    "In time: "+inhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nOut time: "+outhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nDuration: "+hour+"hours and "+minute+"minutes."+
                                                                    "\nVehicle Type: "+typeVehicle+
                                                                    "\nParking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,receipt,"Vehicle Parking System - Parking Receipt",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                                            else
                                                {double calcalateDuration = hour + (minute/60);
                                                double fee = calcalateDuration*140/100;
                                                String show = "Parking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,show,"Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please take your receipt.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                String receipt =    "In time: "+inhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nOut time: "+outhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nDuration: "+hour+"hours and "+minute+"minutes."+
                                                                    "\nVehicle Type: "+typeVehicle+
                                                                    "\nParking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,receipt,"Vehicle Parking System - Parking Receipt",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                                            break;

                            case "Lorry" :  if (minute <0)
                                                {minute = minute +60;
                                                hour = hour - 1;
                                                double calcalateDuration = hour + (minute/60);
                                                double fee = calcalateDuration*160/100;
                                                String show = "Parking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,show,"Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please take your receipt.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                String receipt =    "In time: "+inhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nOut time: "+outhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nDuration: "+hour+"hours and "+minute+"minutes."+
                                                                    "\nVehicle Type: "+typeVehicle+
                                                                    "\nParking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,receipt,"Vehicle Parking System - Parking Receipt",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                                            else
                                                {double calcalateDuration = hour + (minute/60);
                                                double fee = calcalateDuration*160/100;
                                                String show = "Parking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,show,"Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please take your receipt.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                                String receipt =    "In time: "+inhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nOut time: "+outhourInput+" "+inminuteInput+
                                                                    "\nDuration: "+hour+"hours and "+minute+"minutes."+
                                                                    "\nVehicle Type: "+typeVehicle+
                                                                    "\nParking fee: "+fee;
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,receipt,"Vehicle Parking System - Parking Receipt",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                                            break;
                            default     :   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unknown Error Occurred!","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                            break;}}


                    else
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Process Canceled.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Process Canceled.","Vehicle Parking System",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);



   }
}
```

I've been stucked here for half a day, maybe not long enough for some people. But I really do need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear; you are receiving an error when you _compile_? At what line number?

Comment: I've edit the post with additional result shows that I've received the Exception error while compiling without using try and catch ways.

Comment: OK, the lower example with the try/catch approach is a better one **if** you fix the scoping issue with the variables. You should always try to catch number exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, it appears the line that is causing the problem is:

```
double outhourInput = Double.valueOf(outhour);
```

The exception trace referenced indicates that outhour is empty/null. Therefore, prior to the conversion, check to see if outhour is empty (e.g., `outhour != null && ! outhour.trim().isEmpty()`).

Having copied the code (from the 2nd example) into an IDE, it is quickly clear where the problem is. You *do not* have a problem with NumberFormatException *per se*. The problem, which is in multiple places, is a scope issue with the variables.

```
       if (choice == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        try {
            String inhour = inh.getText();  //-->inhour defined here
            double inhourInput = Double.valueOf(inhour);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            if (inhour == null || inhour.equals("")) {  //-->no scope for inhour
                inhourInput = 0.0;
            }
            else {
                inhourInput = 0.0;
            }
        }
```

In all of your blocks, you must ensure that the defined variable is in scope in the catch blocks. However, I do not see the point of the if tests since they all set to the variable to 0.0 anyway.

Try an approach such as:

```
double inhourInput = 0.0;
String inhour = inh.getText();
try {
   inhour = inh.getText();
   inhourInput = Double.valueOf(inhour);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // do not really need to reset to 0, but can be useful for clarity
  inhoutInput = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Great solution for me. It totally solved my problem. Thanks alot! Though i receive a minor error about the "inhour" has declared twice. But it can be solve easily. Thanks again!

Comment: @LeonSeveron, you are correct, I failed to remove the String declaration in the `try {` as I moved things around. Made the edit. Glad it helped.